# Get specific frames using EmguCv

Tags: c#, video-capture, emgucv

I have a EmguCv.Capture in 'Movie' class.
I want to create a function that get a frame number and return this frame, like:

```
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;

Class Movie
{
   private Capture capture;
   public Movie(string FileName)
   {
     capture=new Capture(FileName);
     ...
   }
   public Image<Bgr, byte> GetFrame(int FrameNum)
   {
    //return the FrameNum frame
   }
}
```

I need to do that as quickly as possible.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using [`SetCaptureProperty`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.0.0.0/html/b30a1246-f8ff-37bf-c8be-f47d110c5b66.htm) method:

```
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;

Class Movie
{
   private Capture capture;
   public Movie(string fileName)
   {
     capture = new Capture(fileName);
     ...
   }
   public Image<Bgr, byte> GetFrame(double frameNum)
   {
        capture.SetCaptureProperty(CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frameNum);
        return capture.QueryFrame();
   }
}
```